# Trying to find any rows in a table shared by two other keys (in same table)

Tags: sqlite

I'm looking for a little help with some SQLite. I'm trying to write a query in a simple a way as possible. That is, with SQL statements rather than retrieving a set of data, then another set and comparing them by iterating through both.

Looking at the extract of a table below:  I know both parent IDs and I want to find all the children IDs they have in common.  So parent 291 & 673 have 755 in common.  They could have one, or more, children in common.

How can I write a select statement to find 755?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.
David

[image]

Comment: Ok, I think I have figured it out, however is this the most efficient way?

`SELECT ZCHILD from ZPCREL where ZCHILD IN (SELECT ZCHILD FROM ZPCREL where ZPARENT=673) AND ZPARENT=291;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a group for each child of those parents, and then search for  groups that have both parents:

```
SELECT zChild
FROM zPcRel
WHERE zParent IN (291, 673)
GROUP BY zChild
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Alternatively, use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to intersect the sets of children of both parents:

```
SELECT zChild FROM zPcRel WHERE zParent = 291
INTERSECT
SELECT zChild FROM zPcRel WHERE zParent = 673
```

Your own query would work, too:

```
SELECT zChild
FROM zPcRel
WHERE zChild IN (SELECT zChild
                 FROM zPcRel
                 WHERE zParent = 673)
  AND zParent = 291
```

Which of these queries is most efficient depends on the shape of the data and what indexes there are; you have to measure.

Answer (score 0):

A self-join is probably the most efficient way to do this -

SELECT DISTINCT(a.zchild) FROM  a,  b 
WHERE (a.zparent = 291 OR a.zparent = 293) AND (a.zchild = b.zchild AND a.zparent <> b.zparent)